How the given callback function to filter method is eleminating the missing values in the array?
//Javascript code snippet
let sparse = [5, , 3, , 1];
let dense = sparse.filter(() => true);
console.log(dense);

The callback function is a no-arg function. How it removes the vacant elements?
The output is:
[5, 3, 1]
How?

MDN documentation

let dense = sparse.filter((elem) => { console.log(elem); return true}); shows clearly that the filter does not even access the unassigned slots, so that is why.

Thank you Mr mplungjan for your reply. Yes it is true that filter method by default skips the missing element in sparse array. In your explanation the arrow function is taking one argument hence it's working is very clear. But in the given example how the no arg callback function is working that is not being clear. Can you please explain it's functioning?

From mdn docs, linked by Ry in comments:

callbackFn is invoked only for array indexes which have assigned values.
It is not invoked for empty slots in sparse arrays.


In filter method the call back function is a predicate function and is called on each array element on which filter method is invoked. But here the arrow function is returning true when calling with no argument. That is the point of ambiguity.
